# How can I access to an attribute from a dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary, attributes

so I have a Class Number with two string attributes called roman and text (It is supposed to store the Roman value and text description of an Arabic number)

I use a dictionary to store this information, the keys are the Arabic numbers and the values are instances of the class Number.

Finally, I want to print the attributes but I cannot find the way to access them.

Example:

```
number = Number("XX", "twenty")
dictionary {20:number}
```

So when I print the Arabic number and its roman value and tex description I want to get this output:

```
20 XX twenty
```

I thought that in order to get this I would have to code:

```
print("20 " + dictionary.get(20).roman + " " + dictionary.get(20).text)
```

But that is not the case, does someone know how to access the attributes of the object from a dictionary?

Comment: What is the problem? You got the object with `dictionary.get(20)` and accessed the attribute with `dictionary.get(20).roman`.

Comment: Why do you think "that is not the case"? Did you get an exception or something?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of accessing is storing the key and the value in temporary variables to be used in printing (or something else), *rather than manually typing in 20*.

```
k = 20                         # key
v = dictionary[k]              # value
roman, text = v.roman, v.text
```

If you want to do this in a loop (to print all elements),

```
for k in dictionary:
    v = dictionary[k]
    roman, text = v.roman, v.text
```

Or using [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict.items),

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    print(k, v.roman, v.text)
```